# SQL Server linked server losing Windows authentication credentials

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, linked-server

We are seeing a *sporadic* authentication issue between two SQL Server instances with linked servers where the Windows authentication credentials are sometimes lost on the remote server.  When this occurs, we see logon failures in the remote server's SQL logs saying:

> Source     Logon
>
> Message
> Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 10.xxx.xxx.xxx]

The origin server has a linked server pointing to the remote instance with pass-through authentication.  I.e. on the Security page of the linked server properties, we have selected "For a login not defined in the list above, connections will: **Be made using the login's current security context**".

The linked server is set up as:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'KITTYHAWK', @srvproduct=N'SQLSERVER', @provider=N'SQLNCLI11', @datasrc=b.xyz.com', @catalog=N'Kittyhawk'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'KITTYHAWK',@useself=N'True',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=NULL,@rmtpassword=NULL
```

The domain account the application process runs as has db_datareader access via an Active Directory group present on the remote server (as well as the source server).  The application connects to the origin server with connection string `Data Source=a.xyz.com;Initial Catalog=MPR;Integrated Security=SSPI;`

Both instances are on SQL Server 2016 (13.0.5850.14) and are in the same AD domain.

We have verified the SPNs for both servers are set up and include the SQL Server service accounts and domain names used in all the connections (app to source instance, and source instance linked server to remote).

The application works most of the time, so the setup seems valid.  Plus users who have access to both databases like myself can query across the linked server no problem.

The only type of pattern we have noticed is when this issue occurs, we see many instances of it in the remote server's log at the same time.  For example, the last instance had 13 logon errors in the same second, and none before that for 3+ hours.  The application usage does make a lot of queries across the linked server in processing, and automatic retries within the application usually succeed a second or so later.

Is there any type of Active Directory/Kerberos authentication usage limits and how would we check this?

Any other possible causes?

Comment: My guess would be spotty AD connections - are you self hosting the AD, in the cloud, etc? Any SA teams who could help?

Comment: @LowlyDBA-JohnMcCall - AD is self-hosted on premises as are the SQL Server instances

Comment: Did you rule-out network issue? Possibly, network is not very stable during that time when you face the issue.

Comment: You could, as a test, change the linked server connection type to a sql one, add permissions on the sql side, and see what happens with the error.